# Conflicting URL Rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the below in my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/view.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/display.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Both rewrite to get URL as `http://domain.com/some-file-name`. With the way it is, the browser interprets whchever rewrite rule comes first in the line when a link is clicked at since URLs are of same format.

How do I fix it to understand what URL to interpret and display correctly still maintaining the same URL structure.

*Currently, if I move the #2 above, it starts interpreting #2 and if I allow as it is, it interprets #1. Please I need some help here.*

Comment: If there is no constant difference between the two, you are not able to do it with `.htaccess` alone. You can use a router php page though that will make an intelligent choice.

Comment: @Sumurai8 How does the router page work? Can you give a sample and explain further please.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Right now, both lines are rewriting with the same criteria (all alphanumeric text). If you want them to rewrite different URLs, you need to either make your REGEX more specific in your rewrite rule or add a rewrite condition, e.g. RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/view.php?cat=$1

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here, either. An URL can either be rewritten in to one thing, or another. There is no way to rewrite an URL into two different URLs at the same time.

Comment: @djh101 Will adding RewriteRule `^view/`([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/view.php?cat=$1 not cause the URL to have `/view/` in it? I aim to keep it without of such. I want it as simple as `http://domain.com/some-file-name`

Comment: @Pekka웃 The two rules in the htaccess are for different pages but clicking at links, get just RULE 1 interpreting and overriding RULE 2 not minding what RULE is expected to interpret the clicked URL. If I put RULE 2 above RULE 1 then it takes precedence and overrides the other. You understand better now?

Comment: Well there has to be some criteria for determining which rule is used. As it is, you are trying to rewrite a single URL to two different things. To use a math analogy, a function can only logically give you one output for every input; if x = 2, f(x) can't be 3 and 4 at the same time.

Comment: If they are for different pages, then you need to set up different rules instead of the blanket `^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$`. No way around that. What tells the URLs apart, can you make some examples?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Nothing actually as all the URLs are in the format `http://domain.com/some-file-name` but are formed from different pages, `view.php` and `display.php`. I am trying not to rewrite as `http://domain.com/v/some-file-name`. Can I achieve such?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't get all of the last post. No, it will not contain view. The left part of RewriteRule is merely the conditions for the rewrite (i.e. the format of the original URL); the right side alone determines the destination URL. The $1 will display the content within the first set of parenthesis, but /view/ will not be included unless you add it manually.

Comment: @djh101 I tried it (`RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/view.php?cat=$1 [L]`) but it returns a "Page not found" if done for both but if done for just "1" it works fine while the second fails.

Comment: ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ would be a URL something like http://domain.com/view/filename (if your URL is not of that format, it will not be rewritten). You don't have to use /view/, but there does have to be something in your URL that can be used to distinguish between URLs that are rewritten as view.php and URLs that are rewritten as display.php.

Comment: @djh101 Once I give a proper distinction with a `/view/filename` in the link, it works fine. But I want to eliminate the "/view/". How can I get it worked out. Any ideas?

Comment: What criteria is being used to determine the destination URL (i.e. what should cause one page to go to view.php versus display.php and vice versa)?

Comment: @djh101 Under normal condition, `/view/filename` gets the `view.php` and works fine as well as `/display/filename`. I want to write my URL and eliminate the "/view/" and "/display/". That got me stuck as with what I came up with, any of the Rules that comes first presides over the other thereby resulting to some correct and erroneous URLs. My challenge has been to fix all to have same clean URL with the "/view/" etc. Is there a way to add in anything even after the entire URL as a differentiating factor?

Comment: @djh101 Any further clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your comments you asked:

> `If I were to make URL become http://domain.com/some-file-name for
>   "view.php" and http://domain.com/some-file-name---[id] for
>   "display.php" where "[id]" will be the "group_id" number in the
>   database, will it make a difference in their URL and cause it to
>   rewrite well?`

Yes this will be possible with following rules:

```
# first try to see if belongs to /j/view.php based on URI pattern
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)---([0-9]+)/?$ /j/view.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# No try /j/display.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /j/display.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for you lead. I tried the implementation but it redirects all to display.php RULE. Any other leads? This really has gotten me so weak failing to get it working. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: What URL did you use for testing?

Comment: Only if URL is like `/some-file-name---10` then it will goto `/j/view.php` otherwise it will goto `/j/display.php` I have already tested above code and it works fine.

Comment: Great! You rock man! Others too that helped, YOU ALL ARE GREAT MEN HELPING DISTANT BROTHERS IN NEED.

Comment: Glad you got your solution. Sorry to leave so suddenly last night, but I have to get up at 5 to catch my bus.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no constant difference between the url's, you cannot constantly split the requests between those two pages. I recommend changing the url's so that each of the two pages have their own prefix.

```
RewriteRule ^c-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/view.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^n-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/display.php?name=$1 [L]
```

If you don't wish to do that, you'll have to make a router page that intelligently splits the requests between your two pages. You would have a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /j/router.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And a file `router.php` with something like the following code. Obviously I can't tell what the difference is between the two. Maybe you can match it against a database or something.

```php
<?php
if( condition to check $_GET['page'] for view.php ) {
  $_GET['cat'] = $_GET['page'];
  include( '/j/view.php' );
} else {
  $_GET['name'] = $_GET['page'];
  include( '/j/display.php' );
}
```

Comment: Please give me a sample of what conditions I should be checking here. Pages are called from database as well. `view.php` gets "all created groups" in my program while `display.php` display particular information about each groups.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to do that on your own. I can't magically have knowledge about your entire backend and in all honesty, you should be able to create that condition yourself...

Comment: If I get an idea of the kinda condition then I should be able to. I already tried the GET requests which should get pages from the DB but I get a total white page with no errors. That's was I asked as it got me entirely lost as I have no errors displayed to know where to take my bearing from.

Comment: Check the error log on the server (error notification in the browser is probably turned off for security reasons?). `var_dump` your condition for various url's to see when it is true and when it is not.

Comment: I have no errors on my log and my var_dump is empty. If I were to make URL become `http://domain.com/some-file-name` for "view.php" and `http://domain.com/some-file-name---[id]` for "display.php" where "[id]" will be the "group_id" number in the database, will it make a difference in their URL and cause it to rewrite well?

Comment: Please if you can, assist me as I'm still stuck.